# Angular 4 : How to set the previous form to edit mode when back button click in stepper

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material2

I am new to Angular ,Here in my application I am using Angular material designs .

Now I have a stepper component,I just have the default editable stepper.What I want to do is need to customize the stepper as the follows.

The current code is working as :

- If I clicked on the **Enable edit mode** button the steps are
  editable at any point(Edit icon enabled in all the steps) .If I clicked **Disable edit mode** It will not
  get edited.

I want it as :

- I need to remove the **Enable/Disable Mode button**
- If I clicked on the back button from the current form the previous form should be get editable mode instead of all the forms/steps.

Stackblitz :https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stacb4-h9mkge?file=app/snack-bar-overview-example.html

can anyone help me to get this ...

Answer (score 1):

I have set

```
[editable]="true"
```

in all the sections and remove the button "Enable edit mode".

New logic. If you're input is validated you can continue to the next step. You can always return to all the previous steps. But, if some step is not validated, you can't continue to the next step.

You can see the example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stacb4-luccax?file=app%2Fsnack-bar-overview-example.ts).

**EDIT**

Changes are made with dynamically setting the step variable and enabling/disabling certain steps.

On the change of selection the selectionChange function is fired and you can get the selectedIndex and previouslySelectedIndex. The selectedIndex is enough in this case.

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper linear #stepper (selectionChange)="selectionChange($event)">
```

The step variable gets updated every time the event is fired

```
selectionChange = ($event) => {
  this.step = $event.selectedIndex;
}
```

Then, you can enable/disable certain depending on the step.

```
<mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup" [editable]="step == 0 || step == 1">
```

You can see the example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stacb4-luccax?file=app%2Fsnack-bar-overview-example.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response Brother,your solution is slight different from my expectation .If I clicked on back button of the current step the previous step only get edit mode instead of all the previous steps .

Comment: Ex : assume I have clicked the back button of third step ,Now the second step should be in edit mode but the first step should be in saved move (first step's icon should be shown as a Tic icon instead of edit icon)..Brother hope you understand my problem

Comment: Bro ,can you help me in this ...@Gregor Ojstersek